# Comparing Button.Background with Colors

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am building a Windows Store application. I am facing a problem when trying to compare the background with a color.

What My Program Does. There are many buttons on the screen and on a click of any button it changes the background color of it to either red or green. Starting from Red and switching color per click.Now I want that the buttons that already have been clicked, their `background` should not change. Thus the background checking `if` statement to skip the `background` color change code.

This is my code:

```
private void changecolor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    if ((sender as Button).Background != "Red" && (sender as Button).Background != "Green")
    {
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
            (sender as Button).Content = "Green";

            counter = 0;
        }
        else if (counter == 0)
        {  
            (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
            (sender as Button).Content = "Red";

            counter = 1;
        }
    }      
}
```

On the first `if` statement, I want to check if the `Background` is not `Red` or `Green`.

`(sender as Button).Background != Windows.UI.Colors.Red`

`(sender as Button).Background != "Red"`

The above code doesn't work.

---

What Do I write in Place of "Red" to make the comparison work?

Comment: Perhaps the error code you are seeing could be helpful.  You can see that you are setting the `Background` property value to a `SolidColorBrush`, which is obviously not the same as a `string` with the name of a color.

Comment: @dubstylee Here are the errors
Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush' and 'Windows.UI.Color'

Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush' and 'string'

Comment: Short answer: replace `"Red"` with `Brushes.Red`.  More detailed answer below.

Comment: It is a Brush, there are several possible concrete brush types.  Depends on how you designed it.  Maybe you can cast Background to (SolidColorBrush), a common choice, now you can use its Color property.  Could also be GradientBrush or TileBrush, they don't have just one color of course.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, casting the background worked well. Thank you for your help I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have gotten the answer to this.

> Thank you @dub stylee and @Hans Passant

I caste the `background` as a `solidcolorbrush` then used its `color` property and compared it to the `Windows.Ui.Colors.Green`

Here is the code.

```
if (((sender as Button).Background as SolidColorBrush).Color != Windows.UI.Colors.Green && ((sender as Button).Background as SolidColorBrush).Color != Windows.UI.Colors.Red)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the MSDN documentation for the `Control` class (which `Button` inherits from):

```
void ChangeBackground(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (btn.Background == Brushes.Red)
    {
        btn.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.LightBlue, Colors.SlateBlue, 90);
        btn.Content = "Control background changes from red to a blue gradient.";
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Background = Brushes.Red;
        btn.Content = "Background";
    }
}
```

The full article can be viewed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=vs.110).aspx).

So to apply this to your current code, you can simply change your first `if` statement to look like this:

```
var redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
var greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

if ((sender as Button).Background == redBrush ||
    (sender as Button).Background == greenBrush)
```

Comment: what header is Brushes using because I cannot seem to add it to my code. Brushes does not exist in current context

Comment: `System.Windows.Media`

Comment: I cannot add that header. here are my headers..
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Diagnostics;`
I have brush not brushes..Doesn't work like brushes

Comment: I suppose if `Brushes.Red` doesn't work, you can try `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)` instead.

Comment: `if ((sender as Button).Background != new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) && (sender as Button).Background != new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) )`

Both the codes do not Give Error but they still do not work.

Comment: Have you gotten this working yet?  Also, please add to your question explaining what you are trying to do.  I think you may need to change the `&&` in your `if` to `||` instead, and the `!=` to `==`.  It looks like you are trying to alternate the background color between `Green` and `Red`, but if the background color is `Green` or `Red` then your `if` statement will be `false` and not reach the inner code that changes the background color.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your help I have posted the answer.